# Required field not working after including pattern in name - Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I'm passing through awkward situation.

All rules working fine except `required` field for `first_name`.

```
'FirstNameLength' => ['first_name', 'string', 'min' => 3, 'tooShort'=>'First name should contain atleast 3 character'],
'FirstNameTrim' => ['first_name', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
'FirstNameRequired' => ['first_name', 'required','message'=>'* First name is required'],
'FirstNameRequired' => ['first_name','match','pattern'=>"/^[a-zA-Z']+$/",'message' => '* First Name can only contain alphabets charater'],
```

And, It is happening after including `pattern` in rules. If I remove or comment the `pattern` rules, it is working.

```
'FirstNameLength' => ['first_name', 'string', 'min' => 3, 'tooShort'=>'First name should contain atleast 3 character'],
'FirstNameTrim' => ['first_name', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
'FirstNameRequired' => ['first_name', 'required','message'=>'* First name is required'],
//'FirstNameRequired' => ['first_name','match','pattern'=>"/^[a-zA-Z']+$/",'message' => '* First Name can only contain alphabets charater'],
```

My motive was not to allow any `space`, `number`, or `special character` except `'`. And, this pattern rules working fine as I wanted. But, Only problem is Now it's not taking `required` rule.

Any Help/Hints/Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I . don't understand your notation .. what's means FirstNameLength, FirtsNameTrim ,,, and so .. on could you provide more info and/or the related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are redefining/overrider  the key  `FirstNameRequired`  then the last override the previous  ..

i suggest you the use of normal notation for validation rules (without FirstNameRequired key

```
['first_name', 'required','message'=>'* First name is required'],
['first_name','match','pattern'=>"/^[a-zA-Z']+$/",'message' => '* First Name can only contain alphabets charater'],
```

Comment: Wow. Great. I didn't noticed that. *Salute* @Scais. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @NanaPartykar  ... salve .. .. (mean hello .. in my country)